# Joint query across 2 models (has_many)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, subquery, associations

Hi I need help and all insight appreciated. I have two models Auctions and Bids and I want to retrieve the All auctions current_user won, the ones s/he has been outbid on and the ones s/he's winning

Here are the two models:

```
class Auction < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :guid, use: :slugged
  before_save :populate_guid
  mount_uploaders :images, ImageUploader
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :bids, dependent: :destroy
  has_one  :order, dependent: :destroy
  validates_presence_of :title, :lien_price,
                    :end_time, :collateral_value,
                    :redemption_date, :current_interest_rate,
                    :additional_tax, :collateral_details,
                    :location, :client_id, :starting_bid
  validate :end_time_in_the_future, :on => :update
  validates_uniqueness_of :guid, case_sensitive: false  
  def end_time_in_the_future
    errors.add(:end_time, "can't be in the past") if self.end_time &&   self.end_time < Time.now
  end
  def self.get_active_auctions
    where("end_time > ?", Time.now)
  end
  def self.closed_auctions
    where("end_time < ?", Time.now)
  end
  def highest_bid
    self.bids.maximum("amount")
  end
  def highest_bid_object
    self.bids.order(:amount => :desc).limit(1).first
  end
  def highest_bidder
    self.highest_bid_object.user if highest_bid_object
  end
  def closed?
    self.end_time < Time.now
  end
  private 
  def populate_guid
    if new_record?
      while !valid? || self.guid.nil?
        self.guid = SecureRandom.random_number(1_000_000_000).to_s(36)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :guid, use: :slugged
  belongs_to :auction
  belongs_to :user
  before_save :populate_guid
  validates_presence_of :amount, :user_id,
                    :auction_id

 #validate :higher_than_current?
 validates :amount, :numericality => true
 validates_uniqueness_of :guid, case_sensitive: false   
 def higher_than_current?
   if !Bid.where("amount > ? AND auction_id = ?", amount, self.auction.id).empty?
  errors.add(:amount, "is too low! It can't be lower than the current bid, sorry.")
  end  
end
private 
  def populate_guid
    if new_record?
      while !valid? || self.guid.nil?
        self.guid = SecureRandom.random_number(1_000_000_000).to_s(36)
      end
    end
  end  
end
```

I thought

```
@auctions = Auction.closed_auctions.where(highest_bidder: current_user)
```

or

```
@auctions = Auction.closed_auctions.joins(:bids).where(highest_bidder: current_user)
```

would work but they both raise an error.

Edit this works

```
@auctions = Auction.closed_auctions.references(highest_bidder: current_user)
```

But there's probably a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can't access current_user from controller (devise?). So you need to pass the user as a parameter to the class or instance method. What you should look into are scopes and especially scopes that accept parameters. Scopes could really help you refactor your Auction model (you really don't need any methods that only return a where()), but also solve the inaccessible current_user.

Use it like this in your Auction model:

```
scope: :highest_bidder -> (current_user) { where(highest_bidder: current_user) }
```

And call it like this from your controller:

```
@auctions = Auction.closed_auctions.highest_bidder(current_user)
```